# How count process in windows server 2008 with a command or a bat file?

Tags: batch-file, process, count, pipeline

If I write 
tasklist > procesos.txt | find /v /c "" < procesos.txt
count three lines more,
¿how Can I put this code in a variable and then I can subtract 3?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a "num=%%a-3"
echo %num%
```

Execute the `tasklist`, pipe its output into `find` to do the count, capture the output with a `for` command that will retrieve it into its replaceable parameter and do the arithmetic over this parameter to get the required count